# File upload issue in google cloud storage using node.js server hosted in google app engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

In my node js server , I want to upload an image to Google Cloud Storage. I am using this route to post the image:

```
router.post(
    '/upload-to-gcp',
    uploadTestImages.single('testImage'),
    async (req, res) => {
        try {
            if (req.file) {
                const filePath = req.file.path;
                const fileName = req.file.originalname;
                const destination = 'someFolderInBucket/' + fileName;

                try {
                    const file = await storageService.uploadFile(
                        filePath,
                        destination
                    );

                    const publicFile = await storageService.makeFilePublic(
                        file
                    );
                    const publicUrl =
                        storageService.getFilePublicUrl(publicFile);
                    console.log(
                        `Public URL for ${publicFile.name}: ${publicUrl}`
                    );

                    res.status(200).send('Image uploaded successfully');
                } catch (error) {
                    res.status(500).send('Error uploading image');
                }
            } else {
                res.status(400).send('No file uploaded');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).send('My custom error message', error);
        }
    }
);
```

'uploadTestImages.single('testImage')' is a multer middleware used to store the image inside the 'tmp' folder.

Here are the functions for reference:

```
const testImageStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        try {
            cb(null, './tmp/uploads/testing/');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('An error occurred in destination:', error);
            cb(error);
        }
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        try {
            cb(null, new Date().getTime() + file.originalname);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('An error occurred in filename:', error);
            cb(error);
        }
    },
});

const uploadTestImages = multer({
    storage: testImageStorage,
    limits: { fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 3 },
    fileFilter: fileFilter,
});
```

Everything works fine locally, and I can upload the image to the bucket. However, when I deploy the code to a live server hosted on Google Cloud Platform (google app engine) as serverless, it doesn't work. It gives the error 'Error: EROFS: read-only file system.' I suspect the problem is that it cannot upload my file to the folder. Can anyone suggest how I can solve this error?"

Answer (score 0):

Solve this issue.  The problem is in 'multer' testImageStorage function I defined the path like this  '/uploads/testing/'. It works fine locally and on all other servers but in GCP, I need to change the path like this 'tmp/uploads/testing/' and it is working now.